# Children of different parents - cross married

Tags: genealogytree

Hi I would like to draw a situation, when two sons of are getting married two daughters like on the diagram. I have code like this:

```
parent{
    g{Children1}
    parent {
        g{Son1}
        c{Son2}
        p{GrandFather1}
        p{GrandMother1}
    }           
    parent{
        g{Daugher1}
        c{Daugher2}
        p{GrandFather2}
        p{GrandMother2}
    }
}
```

How to add a second marriage and children?
Is it possible with Latex genealogyTree?

Thanks for help!

[image: cross marriage]

Answer (score 1):

You can represent a complex tree by adjusting the relative positions of several trees (for example with `adjust position`) and linking the families (for example with `add parent`).

Once the relations are written, you can adjust the edges positions (for example with `edges down by`or `pivot shift`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \genealogytree{
            child{
                g{Grand Father 1}
                p[id=grandmother2]{Grand Mother 1}
                c[id=son1]{Son 1}
                c[id=son2]{Son 2}
            }
        }
        \genealogytree[
            adjust position=grandfather2 right of grandmother2 distance 1.6cm,
            add parent=son1 to fam_daughter1,
            add parent=son2 to fam_daughter2
        ]{
            child{
                g[id=grandfather2]{Grand Father 2}
                p{Grand Mother 2}
                child[id=fam_daughter1, edges down by= 1 of 6, pivot shift=-2.6cm]{
                    g{Daughter 1}
                    c{Children 1}
                }
                child[id=fam_daughter2, edges up by= 1 of 6, pivot shift=-2.6cm]{
                    g{Daughter 2}
                    c{Children 2}
                }
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]